# passing SaveChangesOptions to BeginSaveChanges

Tags: c#, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api, odata, async-await

I have a very simple question since I'm new to these OData stuff :

How to pass SaveChangesOptions property when using BeginSaveChanges method in OData, here is my code and pattern :

```
MoviesService.Container _proxy;
```

Initialize _proxy in constructor, and here is the other code :

```
private async void Save_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await SaveAsych();
}

private Task<DataServiceResponse> SaveAsych()
{
    return Task.Factory.FromAsync<DataServiceResponse>(_proxy.BeginSaveChanges,
        _proxy.EndSaveChanges, null);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to pass SaveChangesOptions property when using BeginSaveChanges
>   method in OData

Use lambdas:

```
private Task<DataServiceResponse> SaveAsych(SaveChangesOptions options)
{
    return Task.Factory.FromAsync<DataServiceResponse>(
         (asyncCallback, asyncState) =>
             _proxy.BeginSaveChanges(options, asyncCallback, asyncState),
         (asyncResult) =>
             _proxy.EndSaveChanges(asyncResult), null);
}
```

Comment: Hi... thanks for answering... but it gives me compilation error : Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.IAsyncResult' because it is not a delegate type...

Comment: That's Wonderful... God bless you... Thanks

Comment: I didn't know I can up vote posts now... because I just got the permission to do... :)

Comment: @Kourosh, congrats! One shot, two kills :)

Answer (score 0):

If you get a delegate type error, make sure you're using the correct namespace:

```
private Task<Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceResponse> SaveAsych(Microsoft.OData.Client.SaveChangesOptions options)
    {
        return Task.Factory.FromAsync<Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceResponse>(
             (asyncCallback, asyncState) =>
                 c.BeginSaveChanges(options, asyncCallback, asyncState),
             (asyncResult) =>
                 c.EndSaveChanges(asyncResult), null);
    }
```